# Rewrite rules without changing uri in Nginx

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, uri, proxypass

How can I rewrite an uri without returning a redirect in the process in Nginx ? 
The rewrite result is in the same host.

Exemple: rewrite "`mysite.com/foo`" returning the same result as "`mysite.com/bar`", but we dont change the uri in the process.

It's kinda like a `proxy_pass` but for the same host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can proxy_pass to host+uri.

```
location  ~ ^/foo/(.*)$ {
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1/bar/$1;
}
```

Or rewrite and proxy_pass should work:

```
location  ~ ^/foo {
    rewrite ^foo(.*) /bar$1
    proxy_pass   http://example.com;
}
```

I hope any of those 2 works for you.